# How to re-import in R with delimiters

Tags: r, import, delimiter

My data looks something like this:

> [981] "DT:  Journal Article"
>    [982] "PY:  2010"
>    [983] "AN:  1105794"
>    [984] "\\"\n4111,\TI:  Editor's Note"
>    [985] "AF:  U CA, Berkeley"
>    [986] "SO:  American Economic Journal: Economic Policy, 2(2), May 2010, pp. iii"
>    [987] "IS:  1945-7731"
>    [988] "AV:  http://www.aeaweb.org/aej-policy/"
>    [989] "DT:  Journal Article"
>    [990] "PY:  2010"
>    [991] "AN:  1098675"

I currently only have one variable. I want to split this data into two variables, so that observation 987 would have the variable values IS: and "1945-7731" for instance.

I start by using the gsub function:

```
gsub("  ", "ö", data)
```

I use the letter "ö" since it's unique to my language. Since I'm going to use it as a delimiter, I don't want something that might occur naturally in the data.

I then export the data so I can import it again with a delimiter:

```
relevant3<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\sadda\\Desktop\\Assignment\\All3.csv")
```

This seems to have went smoothly. I then try to import my data again:

```
relevant3<-read.delim("C:\\Users\\sadda\\Desktop\\Assignment\\All3.csv", sep="ö")
```

....But I'm treated with the following error message:

> Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote =
>   quote,  :    duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed In addition:
>   Warning message: In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote =
>   quote, dec = dec,  :   EOF within quoted string

Also, though I get my r-object it "still" only consists of one variable. I've tried with more common delimiters (,) but it still doesn't seem to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No need to export and re-import to break up fields. See, e.g., `?tidyr::separate`. I am confused about your desired output - is it only observation 987 that you want to split? What is the splitting logic?

Comment: That was an example, I want to split all observations along the same lines of logic. The only occuring pattern I can use is the two blank spaces between the variable values, so I try to substitute those two spaces into a characther which I can then use as a delimiter.

Comment: Use `tidyr::separate(data, existing_column_name, into = c("result_1", "result_2", sep = "  ")`. If you share your data in a copy/pasteable format, we can help/debug more